# laravel 8: axios.post not working on controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes, axios

I am trying to create a like/dislike button system for blog posts in a project. I am using axios to send a request to the controller in the event of any click on the like or dislike button.

Here is my **script on home blade**

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm " onclick="actOnReact(event);" data-react-id="{{$posts->id}}">Like</button>
                  <p id="likes-count-{{$posts->id}}"> {{$posts->post_like}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                  <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                  
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" onclick="actOnReact(event);" data-react-id="{{$posts->id}}">Dislike</button>
                  <p id="dislikes-count-{{$posts->id}}">{{$posts->post_dislike}}</p>
        </div>
```

---

```
@section('js')
    <script>
        
        var updateReactStats = {
            Like:function (reactId) {
                document.querySelector('#likes-count-' + reactId).textContent++;
            },

            Dislike:function (reactId) {
                document.querySelector('#dislikes-count-' + reactId).textContent++;
            }
        }
        


        var actOnReact = function (event) {
            var reactId = event.target.dataset.reactId;
            var action = event.target.textContent;
            updateReactStats[action](reactId);
            axios.post('/posts/' + reactId + '/react',
                { action: action })
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(error.response.data)
        })
        };

    </script>
    @endsection
```

[image: console log on click frontend responds perfectly]

my **HomeController.php section**

```
 /**
 * increment like or dislike for the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function react(Request $request, $id)
{
  $action = $request->get('action');
    switch ($action) {
        case 'Like':
            Post::where('id', $id)->increment('post_like');
            break;
        case 'Dislike':
            Post::where('id', $id)->decrement('post_dislike');
            break;
    }
    return '';
}
```

My route in **web.php**
Route::resource('posts', PostsController::class);

[image: database don't update post_like]

Comment: You post to `'/posts/' + reactId + '/react'` but your route is `'/chirps/{id}/act'`

Comment: sorry! copied from two parallel projects. Now I edited to correct one but the error remains the same.

Comment: Mainly the same, as the 404 tells you, the route you are posting to doesn't exist. `Route::resource('posts'...` does _not_ make `/posts/{post}/react` available, you'd need to add that route in your web.php first.

Comment: `Route::resource('posts', PostsController::class)` doesn't mean any post request will be routed to PostsController?

Answer (score 1):

Your resource route `Route::resource('posts', PostsController::class);` does *not* make `/posts/{post}/react` available, it only makes CRUD routes (index,create,edit...) available. (A complete list of actions available can be found in the documentation: [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller))

You need to add a route that specifically handles your use case. Add this route to your `web.php`:

```
Route::post('/posts/{id}/react', [PostController::class, 'react']);
```

Comment: but now I get a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)` at the console.

Comment: Have you imported the use statement `use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;` . What does the stack trace show - which line causes the error

Comment: @code-mon Check your `storage/logs/laravel.log` file for the full error. It might be worth clearing/deleting the file, make the request again to produce the error and then check the file again if there's already quite a bit in there.

Comment: `[2020-12-16 17:34:44] local.ERROR: Target class [PostController] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [PostController] does not exist. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravelblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php:811)
[stacktrace]`
so I change the route to `PostsController` the actual file name and run but this time the log is blank and still it doesn't work.